# Touching the antenna of a crystal set

Tags: rf, antenna, receiver, crystal-set

I built the crystal set shown in the diagram below and I find that the signal it receives is clearer when I touch an uninsulated part of the aerial (i.e. the node labelled "green" on the diagram). Would anyone be able to explain why this happens? Thanks.

[image]

(Source: S. Voron, R. Tester and M. Middleton, Funway into Electronics Volume 1. Chullora, NSW: Dick Smith Electronics, 2008)

Comment: What was your earth like - how did you make it?

Comment: My earth is a cold water pipe attached to a bathroom faucet.

Comment: What was the length of your antenna and what frequency band are you aiming for?

Comment: My antenna is a piece of stranded 22 AWG wire that's about 4.5 ft long. The secondary coil of the ferrite rod aerial is 200 uH, so the frequency band would be 890 - 1453 kHz.

Comment: How long is the wire to the cold water pipe?

Comment: About 12 ft long

Comment: You might find that touching the "pink" ferrite-rod wire strengthens signals even more, although you may have to re-tune the variable capacitor to re-peak amplitude. Your body's self-capacitance makes you a better antenna than a 4.5 ft wire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your body is a not too bad antenna .If your antenna system is not very good like say a whip antenna and/or a ferrite rod then the signal addition is going to give a volume increase .These passive receivers do not have automatic gain control so this effect is more pronounced when compared to say a car radio .Your body is also capacitive at AMBC frequencies which will tune the system lower.

Answer (score 2):

> *My antenna is a piece of stranded 22 AWG wire that's about 4.5 ft
> long.*

That's quite short even for a crystal set.

> *the frequency band would be 890 - 1453 kHz*

At 1 MHz, the wavelength is 300 metres so, your 4.5 foot (1.37 metres) antenna represents a proportion of the wavelength of about 0.005. Typically, for a crystal set, you'd be looking at an antenna length around 0.1 \$\lambda\$. In other words, your antenna is about 20 times too short to be reasonably effective.

Question: *How long is the wire to the cold water pipe?*

Answer: *About 12 ft long*

Well, if your earth wire is about 3 times longer than your actual antenna, you have more physical antenna connected to earth than you have on your antenna node. This is a significant problem.

In terms of theory, here's the impedance characteristic of a monopole antenna versus its length compared to operating frequency \$\lambda\$: -

[image]

Much abused image from [here](https://www.aa5tb.com/efha.html).

In other words, your antenna length is right at the left end of the graph and this means tragically poor performance. The radiation resistance is going to be absolutely minuscule and that means absolutely poor signal levels received.

So, you have two problems: -

- You don't really have an antenna that works (until your body that acts as an antenna touches the antenna wire)
- You don't have a ground connection that is reliable (it's longer than the antenna!)

> *I find that the signal it receives is clearer when I touch an
> uninsulated part of the aerial*

All these (above) things mean random performance when your body comes into contact with the circuit. Fix your antenna and shorten your earth wire.

Comment: Interesting answer +1 .Now how does the ferrite rod come into this ? I assume that it is not sheilded and can therefore pick up signal.

Comment: @Autistic it just adds to the unholy mess created by having an ineffective antenna length and a ground wire longer than the antenna.

Comment: @Andy aka I don't have the appropriate materials to construct a 100 ft (30 m) aerial at the moment I'm afraid. Would there be any other alternatives?

Comment: @kene02 this session is closed - you've formally accepted an answer. Where's my motivation to assist further?

Comment: @Andy aka Yeah fair enough. I'll make it as a new post

Comment: @kene02 or you deselect that answer and we'll continue but, if at the end of the day you still want to select a "basic" answer rather than a full tear-down of your problems, then count me out.

Comment: @Andy aka I didn't select Autistic's response because it was "basic", I selected it because they actually explained what was happening when I touched the "aerial" on my wireless which was causing it to receive better. Don't get me wrong, your response taught me a lot of new things, and I gave it an upvote for that reason, but Autistic's response (and glen_geek's comment) were better at addressing my original question.

Comment: @Autistic "how does the ferrite rod come into this?" It will pick up signal but, unless the transmitter is very close, it won't pick up enough to be audible in an earphone without amplication stages. Hence a crystal set requires an additional antenna and earth to get enough signal. I don't have the [constructional article](https://goughlui.com/2014/11/09/tech-flashback-dick-smiths-fun-way-into-electronics-vol-1/) but I assume from the connection colours shown on the circuit that this is a pre-wound ferrite rod aerial sold by Dick Smith Electronics.

Comment: @kene02 then you didn't read my answer correctly.