# Alternatives to a monopole antenna for a crystal set

Tags: rf, antenna, receiver, crystal-set

In my [last post](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/598232/touching-the-antenna-of-a-crystal-set), [@Andy aka](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/20218/andy-aka) recommended that I use a 100 ft (30 m) tall monopole antenna for my crystal set (see diagram below; it has a frequency band of 890 - 1453 kHz). However, I don't have the materials to construct one at the moment. Would there be any other designs which I would be able to use in place of one, preferably one that doesn't have to be as tall?

[image]

(Source: S. Voron, R. Tester and M. Middleton, Funway into Electronics Volume 1. Chullora, NSW: Dick Smith Electronics, 2008)

Comment: You can add a series RF inductor to a short antenna. This makes it seem electrically-longer. There is no substitute for a high, long wire though - don't expect miracles.

Comment: @glen_geek May I ask what value of inductance I should use?

Comment: Can't estimate with any precision - it depends on antenna length/height. You're making an antenna-tuner. Perhaps 10uH -100uH ballpark. If your antenna is *very* short, it may be better to attach it to "pink" spot, but a short, low antenna performs poorly no matter what you do.

Comment: To be clear about what I said in the previous answer. I said that the problem faced was a poor antenna length compared to a much longer wire to earth. I didn't recommend anything; I stated that for 1 MHz, an antenna length of typically 0.1\$\lambda\$ (30 m) would be about right for a crystal set. If you wanted to halve this to 15 metres then, the impedance graph in my answer would predict new performance. Please be careful about what information I gave you in that previous answer and try not to overly misquote me. The whole of my answer is relevant and not fractions of it.

Answer (score 0):

> a 100 ft (30 m) tall monopole antenna

Well, that's impractical. Just try and run as much wire as you can, in a straight(ish) line and preferably outdoors. Get it as high as you reasonably and safely can. Horizontal is fine though running it in different directions may gave different results. Try it and see.

Keep it away from other suspended wiring, both for safety and to reduce pickup of interference.

In your earlier post you mention using a water pipe as your earth. That will work if the water supply to your house is supplied via a metal pipe or the plumbing is bonded (connected) to the electrical mains earth. If not you can make your own earth by driving a metal rod into some ground. (You can get dedicated earth rods from electrical suppliers or use a few feet of copper water pipe.)

Comment: When I had one at the age of 10, I used a wire wrapped around the telephone cord , good for 200 miles, but a long wire from tree to tree to upstairs bedroom window. I could get better reception.

Answer (score 0):

> Would there be any other designs which I would be able to use in place of one, preferably one that doesn't have to be as tall?

A short vertical antenna, used as a ¼ λ monopole, may be made to resonate at the required frequency using a series resonator (loading coil).

M0UKD's 'Loaded Quarter Wave Antenna Inductance Calculator' may be used to arrive at the loading coil inductance.

https://m0ukd.com/calculators/loaded-quarter-wave-antenna-inductance-calculator/

Here's an example of a portable AM crystal radio that uses a short telescopic as a loaded ¼ λ antenna.

[image]

The calculator showed a loading coil inductance of 9 mH, with the distance from the feed point taken as 0 and the wire diameter as 2 mm. Two available 4.7 mH moulded inductors were series-connected for the purpose.

The result was good reception of the local 200 kW, 612 kHz AM radio station even at a distance of 5 km.

Since you have a strong local station nearby, a loading coil would do the trick.

Comment: Crystal sets do not need/use quarter wave monopoles nor do they use antennas that are base loaded to make them appear as quarter wave antennas. The actual shortness of the antenna (and the added capacitive reactance they produce) make them more suitable for use in crystal radios. Hence, suggesting that a base loaded antenna is a good idea is er... not a good idea. We are talking crystal sets here and not modern receivers.

Comment: Hi @Andy aka, I agree with you.  The station kene02 is able to receive with a 4.5' antenna must be a high-power one nearby.  So, I guess, a loading coil would help counter his antenna length constraint.

Comment: You should read the original question. He made serious errors in the earthing wire - it was about three times longer than his 4.5 foot antenna and this thoroughly throws a big spanner in the engine regarding making sense of what body contact may or may not achieve. Adding a loading coil won't help - he should fix the problem and operate with a decent length antenna like anyone else would making a crystal set. Crystal sets can't work with fully quarter wave monopoles because crystal sets make use of the capacitance inherent in a proper short antenna to produce tuning selectivity.